# java threads: stopping all threads when one finishes its task

Tags: java, multithreading

I created two threads with the thread pool, and if one of them is finished, the other threads need to be stopped. How can i achieve?

My idea is to use AtomicBoolean or CountDownLatch to achieve.My code is as follows：

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Thread Pool
    ThreadFactory namedThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("demo-pool-%d").build();
    ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(6, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>(1024), namedThreadFactory, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

    AtomicBoolean atomicBool = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    System.out.println("start");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //If any threads are executed, all threads end immediately
        if (atomicBool.get() == true) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            //do something
            //....
            atomicBool.set(true);
        });
    }

    if (atomicBool.get() == true) {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
    System.out.println("end");
}}
```

But both threads are finished，The result is as follows：

```
start
end
demo-pool-0
demo-pool-1
```

what should I do？

Comment: `atomicBool.get() == true` does not wait until `atomicBool` is `true`.  It checks once.

Comment: Right. Do your checking (atomicBool.get() == true) in a loop until success (you will burn your CPU core. You might add a sleep() to relax CPU pressure, but this isn't elegant) or use Object.wait()/notify() or, better, use an instance of CountDownLatch(1) to await(). CountDownLatch was developed exactly for the cases like your - to wait until something happened

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `AtomicBoolean`, you can use an instance of `CountDownLatch` and pass it to each thread to wait until the countdown value has been reached (in your example the latch would be initialized with 1). The main thread calls `await()` on the latch and that will block until at least one thread has called `countDown()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html